# TeXStudio not loading package documentation

Tags: texstudio

I use TeXstdio to edit my TeX files and used to shift-click on a package name (in `\usepackage` ou `\RequirePackage`) to open the corresponding PDF file.

It's not working for me anymore. When I hover the mouse holding the shift-key the package name turns blue with underline, but when clicked, nothing happens.

**My enviroment**

- Ubuntu eoan 19.10
- GNOME Shell 3.34.1
- TeXstudio 2.12.22
- Texlive installed with the `install-tl` script (see comment below)

Also, both `.bashrc` and `.profile` includes

```
TEXDIR="/usr/local/texlive/2019"
TEXMFCONFIG="~/.texlive2019/texmf-config"
TEXMFHOME="~/texmf"
TEXMFLOCAL="/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local"
TEXMFSYSCONFIG="/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-config"
TEXMFSYSVAR="/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var"
TEXMFVAR="~/.texlive2019/texmf-var"
```

I'm not currently using the `apt` version of `texlive` (from official repositories) because I just couldn't make the package `translator` work properly.

I wasn't able to find any configuration in TeXstudio to set the documentation search path.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Please don't add `[SOLVED]` to the question title. You can accept your own answer and that's enough to show that the issue is solved.

Comment: Nice to know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem.
The `$PATH` to the binaries needed to be set in both `.bashrc` and `.profile`.

Now everthing works just fine!